# iOS - App icon is not showing in Watch Companion app

Tags: xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

For some reason my icon of app has never appeared in **companion** app for **Apple Watch**.

- Icon is appearing in **iPhone** and **Apple Watch** Dashboard.
- I have provided 58*58(29*29@2x) and 76*76(29*29@3x) which are required for Companion Settings.
- From Target Watch, i have selected my asset for Apple Watch.

After doing all that still the icon is not appearing in Companion Settings. What i need to do to make it appear?

Comment: Have you added the icon to the WatchKit `Images.xcassets`? The targets have separated assets files.

Comment: I have the same problem. The only icon not working is the iPhone watch settings companion icon. I have added the correct icon size to the Images.xcassets icon set under the Apple watch Companion Settings 29pt 2x and 3x sections, but its not showing in the simulator or when I deploy it to my phone. I have put the icon set into the Watch App folder and pointed the target Watch App Icon Source to the file but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't find anything regarding this issue elsewhere. Resetting the iPhone and Watch 1-2 times solved this problem.

Comment: What worked for me was to unpair the Watch and then set it up as a new Watch, rather than restoring from a backup. This required confirming the "trust this computer" dialog on the Watch, afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

The WatchKit does not share the `Images.xcassets` file from the main target app.

When adding a WatchKit to your project, it will create 2 folders `<projectname> WatchKit Extension` & `<projectname> WatchKit App`.

You will need to add the Icons for the watch in the `Images.xcassets` file in the WatchKit App folder.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: yeah i from start, have added those images in WatchKit App folder

Comment: Make sure that your WatchApp Target is looking at the correct Icon file. There was a bug with this when the WatchOS first came out but not really had any issues since

Answer (score 1):

I found my project show watch companion app icon right on iOS9.2, but doesn't show the icon on iOS9.1. you can update you IOS version to 9.2,then check if the icon show.